# update oracle dara with select statement

Tags: oracle

I have a table that contains millions of records.I want to update approximately 30.000 rows.
I can get data with `select * from customer where city is not null`. This query returns 30.000 rows.I want to update only that 30000 rows like that

update customer set city = null where (select .....)

I want to update 30.000 rows not all table so I have to use select statement otherwise plain update takes long time :(

Do you have any idea? How can i write a query or script to complete this process.

My trigger is like that,

```
TRIGGER "CUSTOMER_HIST_TR" AFTER
UPDATE OF city ON Customer  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH 
ROW
 DECLARE
  v_osuser varchar2(20);
  v_terminal varchar2(20);
  v_username varchar2(20);
  v_city varchar2(2);
 BEGIN
if nvl(:new.city,'NULL')<>nvl(:old.city,'NULL') then
select osuser,username,terminal
into   v_osuser,v_username,v_terminal
from v$session
where audsid=userenv('SESSIONID');
insert into 
IT_TRG_CITY(customer_id,old,new,osuser,terminal,userid,chng_date) values(:old.customer_id,:old.subs_mask,:new.subs_mask,v_osuser,v_terminal,v_username,sysdate);
end if;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If out of those *millions* of rows 30.000 of them have something in `city` column (and you want to have `null` instead), then

```
update customer set
  city = null
where city is not null;
```

Right?

---

Select you might try instead of yours:

```
SELECT osuser, username, terminal
  INTO v_osuser, v_username, v_terminal
  FROM (SELECT osuser,
               username,
               terminal,
               ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY NULL) rn
          FROM v$session
         WHERE audsid = USERENV ('SESSIONID'))
 WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: It is okey but it gives The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

Comment: Query I posted can NOT return that error. It is ORA-01422, isn't it? Well, there's nothing here that would raise it.

Comment: Yes.I found a trigger on table.Error is giving by trigger .Error during execution of trigger 'CUSTOMER_HIST_TR'
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"

Comment: Fix the trigger code, then.

Comment: I could not fix trigger.I updated my question with my trigger.Can you help me?

Comment: The only SELECT statement is the one that fetches values from v$session, so you should make sure it returns only one row.

Comment: I know select into statement should return only one row but I guess that it returns more than one row.How can I solve this situation.

Comment: See query I posted in the edited answer. Try it.